# how to get the response headers of the initial request to react server (html)

Tags: html, reactjs

i am wondering how can i access the response headers of the initial request to the react server which returns the html of my website. there is a token which is sent in the response headers of the html static server.
i have already printed the window object and did not see anything special about that.

for instance this one :

[image: response header sample]